# How to update record in afterUpdate ( Error: maximum trigger depth exceeded)

Tags: trigger

i try to update field in **afterUpdate** and I got an error like this:

```
 maximum trigger depth exceeded
event AfterInsert DHA_Study_Result trigger 
event AfterUpdate DHA_Study_Result trigger 
event AfterUpdate DHA_Study_Result trigger 
event AfterUpdate DHA_Study_Result trigger 
event AfterUpdate DHA_Study_Result trigger 
event AfterUpdate DHA_Study_Result trigger
```

Here is requirements of my Trigger:

1. When new result study is updated, update *Is_Latest__c* of new records to *true*.
2. There should be 1 latest result associates with *class assignment* so the older results in the same class assignment should have *Is_Latest__c* equals to *false*.

So when result study is updated, i want to update ****Is_Latest__c**** to **true** **(1)**, then
set **Is_Latest__c** to **false** of record which associates with class assignment **(4)** and **(5)**. How i can do that ? Thanks.

**beforeUpdate:**

```
public void beforeUpdate(Map<Id,SObject> newMap) 
{   
    // sObject: DHA_Study_Result__c

    for(Id studyId :newMap.keySet())
    {   
        DHA_Study_Result__c newStudyResult = (DHA_Study_Result__c) newMap.get(studyId);
         // 1. update Is_Latest__c of new records to true when it is updated
        newStudyResult.Is_Latest__c = true; 
    } 
}
```

**afterUpdate:**

```
public void afterUpdate(List<DHA_Study_Result__c> lstStudyResult)
    {   
        Set<Id> idStudyResultSet = new Set<Id>();
        Set<String> classAssignmentSet = new Set<String>();
        // 2. build sets needed to query
        for(DHA_Study_Result__c studyResult :lstStudyResult)
        {
            idStudyResultSet.add(studyResult.Id);
            classAssignmentSet.add(studyResult.DHA_Class_Assignment__c);
        }

        // 3. query record which associates with class assignment (not ourself)
        List<DHA_Study_Result__c> studyResultQuery = [SELECT Is_Latest__c FROM DHA_Study_Result__c 
                                                   WHERE DHA_Class_Assignment__c IN :classAssignmentSet
                                                    AND Id NOT IN :idStudyResultSet ];

        // 4. set Is_Latest__c to false
        for(DHA_Study_Result__c studyResult_toUpdate :studyResultQuery)
        {
            studyResult_toUpdate.Is_Latest__c = false;
        }
        // 5. update record
        update studyResultQuery;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latest updated (// 5.) is updating all the non-last study results. That is correct. But this is, yet again, triggering apex triggers on those non-last study results and *marking them as Is_Latest__c*!!

And therefore again unmarking the rest of the study results as Is_Latest__c, and so on, resulting in an endless loop.

To break the loop, I'd suggest building a mechanism to prevent the triggering from happening if it is being called from this particular update.

I.e.

- implement a `Static Boolean` named `skipMarkAsLatest` and set it to true before doing the update DML (and set it back to false after doing the update, if any other code might still need to trigger it).
- on your before update trigger, only run the code if `skipMarkAsLatest` is false.
- on your after update trigger, also only run the code if `skipMarkAsLatest` is false.

Comment: it work. Many thanks <3